# Combination bike lock

Tags: code-golf, path-finding

### The scenario

After a long day's work slogging in the office and browsing [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com), I finally walk out the door at 16:58, already weary with the day. Because I am still only an intern, my current mode of transportation is on bicycle. I head over to my trusty [Peugeot Reynolds 501](https://lfgss.microco.sm/api/v1/files/e76d534a659b294f031b8d3f92e48357577fbd4b.jpg), but before I can sail away on it, I need to unlock it. The lock is a standard four digit combination lock (0-9), through the frame and the front wheel. As I try to stay awake, I pull my hand up to enter in the combination.
[image: Combination bike lock]

### The challenge

Because my fingers are so weary, I want to turn the lock to the correct combination with the fewest movements. One movement is defined as a rotation by one position (36 degrees), for example there is one movement from `5737` to `5738`. However, I am able to grasp **up to any three consecutive rings at the same time, and rotate them as one**, which only counts as a single movement. For example there is also **only one movement** from `5737` to `6837` or to `5626`. Moving from `5737` to `6838` is not one movement, as digits number 1,2 and 4 have moved in the same direction, but independently of digit number 3.

Therefore, for a given combination I can see on the bike lock (any 4-digit integer), what is the lowest number of movements I can make to get it unlocked, and yes, I can rotate in either direction at any time. By this I mean that I can turn some digits in one direction and other digits in the other direction: not all of my movements will be anitclockwise or clockwise for each unlock.

Because I am lazy, my unlock code is 0000.

<s>This is code golf</s> I can't be bothered writing much code, so the shortest program in number of bytes wins.

Input is from stdin, and your code should output the combinations I can see at each step after each movement, including the 0000 at the end. Each of the combinations output should be separated by a space/newline/comma/period/ampersand.

### Examples

```
Input: 1210
0100
0000

Input: 9871
9870
0980
0090
0000

Input: 5555
4445&3335&2225&1115&0005&0006&0007&0008&0009&0000

Input: 1234
0124 0013 0002 0001 0000
```

I tried posting this on http://bicycles.stackexchange.com, but they didn't like it...

Disclaimer: First golf, so anything that is broken/any missing information let me know! Also I did all the examples by hand, so there may be solutions which involve less movements!

EDIT: For answers which have multiple solution paths with equal number of movements (practically all of them), there is no preferred solution.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG; very nice first challenge!

Comment: This looks solid to me! Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: [tag:path-finding] is an oddly relevant tag.

Comment: Nice challenge. Can i ask what should be the output for cases : 7478 and 3737?

Comment: It's worth noting that if your lock had real numbers written on them and we measured effort by how far we turned a combination, the answer would be writable as the minimum of the dot product of your initial state with a (finite) set of vectors.

Comment: @noisyass2 Thanks; flawr's answer gives the following: 7478
8588
9698
0708
0808
0908
0008
0009
0000

and 
3737
2627
1517
0407
0307
0207
0107
0007
0008
0009
0000

Just looking at the 3737, this makes sense: Looking at the first 3 digits only: If I move all of the first three at the same time, it takes 3 movements for digits 1 and 3, and then another 4 movements for digit 2, thus a total of seven. Whereas if I move each individually, each takes 3 moves, thus 9 movements.

Comment: I'm wondering whether the title "Combination Lock" (or "Bike Lock") might attract more viewers.

Comment: I support @DavidC 's suggestion! PS: Could you please add `4826` or `6284` as test cases? These do need 12 steps, and are (according to my program) the ones who need the greatest minimum number of moves.

Comment: Couldn't decide between "Combination Lock" and "Bike Lock", so I just used both.... And flawr I don't have a working solution, but I've tried that input with a few different methods, and 12 is the best I can find; Either just moving each individually (4 + 2 + 2 + 4 = 12), or digits 1,2,3 at the same time (2), then digits 1,2 (2), then digit 2 (4), and then digit 4 (4), sum = 12. If you follow?

Comment: I would not use a so weak lock on a bike of mine! Minimum should be a U-Lock. The one here is very easy to cut with a n handheld bolt cutter!

Answer (score 10):

## Matlab, <s>412</s> 327 bytes

Golfed (Thanks to @AndrasDeak for golfing `s`!):

```
s=dec2bin('iecbmgdoh'.'-97)-48;s=[s;-s];T=1e4;D=Inf(1,T);P=D;I=NaN(T,4);for i=1:T;I(i,:)=sprintf('%04d',i-1)-'0';end;G=input('');D(G+1)=0;for k=0:12;for n=find(D==k);for i=1:18;m=1+mod(I(n,:)+s(i,:),10)*10.^(3:-1:0)';if D(m)==Inf;D(m)=k+1;P(m)=n-1;end;end;end;end;n=0;X='0000';while n-G;n=P(n+1);X=[I(n+1,:)+48;X];end;disp(X)
```

This codes uses some dynamic programming for finding the shortest 'path' from the given number to `0000` using only the possible steps. The challenge is basically a shortest path prioblem (alternatively you could perhaps consider the steps as a commutatuve group.) but the difficulty was coming up with an *efficient* implementation. The basic structures are two 10000-element arrays, one for storing the number of steps to get to that index, the other one to store a pointer to the previous 'node' in our graph. It simultaneously calculates the 'paths' to all other possible numbers.

Examples:

```
9871
0981
0091
0001
0000

1210
0100
0000

Examples by @noisyass:

7478
8578
9678
0788
0899
0900
0000

3737
2627
1517
0407
0307
0207
0107
0007
0008
0009
0000

Own Example (longest sequence, shared with 6284)

4826
3826
2826
1826
0826
0926
0026
0015
0004
0003
0002
0001
0000
```

Full Code (inlcuding some comments):

```
%steps
s=[eye(4);1,1,0,0;0,1,1,0;0,0,1,1;1,1,1,0;0,1,1,1];
s=[s;-s];


D=NaN(1,10000);%D(n+1) = number of steps to get to n
P=NaN(1,10000);%P(n+1) was last one before n

I=NaN(10000,4);%integer representation as array
for i=0:9999; 
    I(i+1,:)=sprintf('%04d',i)-'0';
end

G=9871; % define the current number (for the golfed version replaced with input('');
D(G+1)=0;
B=10.^(3:-1:0); %base for each digit

for k=0:100; %upper bound on number of steps;
    L=find(D==k)-1;
    for n=L; %iterate all new steps
        for i=1:18; %search all new steps
            m=sum(mod(I(n+1,:)+s(i,:),10) .* [1000,100,10,1]);
            if isnan(D(m+1))
                D(m+1) = k+1;
                P(m+1)=n;
            end
        end
    end
end
n=0;%we start here
X=[];
while n~=G
    X=[I(n+1,:)+'0';X];
    n=P(n+1);
end
disp([I(G+1,:)+'0';X,''])
```

Comment: Nice! Being a mostly Matlab user myself I was wondering about how well it would fare.

Comment: For input `6444` your code gives 6444
7554
8664
9774
0884
0994
0004
0003
0002
0001
0000, whereas I find the answer to be
6444
6333
6222
6111
6000
7000
8000
9000
0000. My answer is 8 steps, yours is 10. I can't see the issue, and it appears to be there in both the golfed and ungolfed version. This is fixed in your latest edit.

Comment: I just corrected a small error in the code. In `s` the last row should be `[0,1,1,1]`. Then you get a 8 step solution too! I'm sorry for the inconvenience=)

Comment: @Lui There is a [matlab/octave](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab-and-octave) chatroom, among other stuff it is some kind of Base for the Matlab-derived golfing languange MATL.

Comment: for 4826, i found an 11 move solution : 
4826
3716
2606
1506
0406
0306
0206
0106
0007
0008
0009
0000

Comment: @noisyass2 How do you get from `0106` to `0007`? =)

Comment: @flawr oh right! it skipped! arrgghhh. nvm then. back to the drawing board.

Comment: But you did make me have some uncomfortable minutes :D

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s>82</s> 73 bytes

```apl
{p/⍨⍵≡¨⊃¨⊢p←({⍵/⍨⍧⊃¨⍵}⊢,⍥,(,∘-⍨↓⍉⊤5~⍨12 14,⍨⍳8)∘.{10|⍵,⍨⊂⍺+⊃⍵}⊢)⍣≡⊂⊂4⍴0}⊆
```

`p←({⍵/⍨⍧⊃¨⍵}⊢,⍥,(,∘-⍨↓⍉⊤5~⍨12 14,⍨⍳8)∘.{10|⍵,⍨⊂⍺+⊃⍵}⊢)⍣≡⊂⊂4⍴0`

p is all the possible paths

`({⍵/⍨⍧⊃¨⍵}⊢,⍥,(,∘-⍨↓⍉⊤5~⍨12 14,⍨⍳8)∘.{10|⍵,⍨⊂⍺+⊃⍵}⊢)`

This is a train that generates the next possible paths from one list of paths

`(,∘-⍨↓⍉⊤5~⍨12 14,⍨⍳8)`

List of possible changes, 0 0 0 0, 0 0 0 1, 0 0 0 -1, etc

`∘.{10|⍵,⍨⊂⍺+⊃⍵}`

Outer product with the dfn `{10|⍵,⍨⊂⍺+⊃⍵}`

`{10|⍵,⍨⊂⍺+⊃⍵}`

`⊃⍵` unenclose ⍵ + `⊂⍺` enclose ⍺

`⍵,⍨` concatenated with ⍵ `10|` mod 10

`⊢,⍥,stuff` concatenate the output with the new paths

`{⍵/⍨⍧⊃¨⍵}` make it unique

`(train)⍣≡⊂⊂4⍴0` apply the train with a fixpoint `⍣≡` to `⊂⊂4⍴0` to generate all paths

`{p/⍨⍵≡¨⊃¨⊢p}`

`⊢p←...` the `⊢` shouldn't be needed here, but that's a bug costing me 1 byte

`⊃¨p` get the first items from each in p

`⍵≡¨` find where ⍵ is equal to them

`p/⍨` replicate

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/v7pA/1Hvike9Wx91Ljy04lFXM4hYVPCobYJGNVAUIrkcIt67tRYop/Ood6mOhs6jjhm6IMm2yY96Ox91LTGtA/IMjRQMTXTAejZbaAKV6FUbGtQANYLFupoe9e7SBpoFNUnzUe9ioLUg8a4mk0e9WwyAom3/04CWP@rtA6tbAxQ9tN74UdvER31Tg4OcgWSIh2fw/zQFUwgEAA)

Old answer:

`{p⌷⍨⍸⍵≡¨⍥⊆⊃¨p←({⍵/⍨≠⊃¨⍵}⊢,⍥,((+,-)↓⍉2⊥⍣¯1⊢⎕A⍳'ABCDFGHLN')∘.{10|⍵,⍨⊂⍺+⊃⍵}⊢)⍣≡⊂⊂4⍴0}`

Answer (score 4):

### Batch - 288 bytes

<s>Even if you said they have to be consecutive (the rings), I assume by logic (following the example) that I can skip the middle one, as from `1234` to `0224`.</s>

```
set/p x=
set a=%x:~0,1%&set b=%x:~1,1%&set c=%x:~2,1%&set d=%x:~3,1%
:l
@echo %x%&if %a%==0 (if %d% NEQ 0 set/a d=d-1) else set/a a=a-1
@if %b% NEQ 0 set/a b=b-1
@if %c% NEQ 0 set/a c=c-1
@if %x% NEQ 0000 set x=%a%%b%%c%%d%&goto l
```

<s>This is my Batch solution: 236 bytes.</s>

---

#### Edit: corrected solution

```
set/p x=
set a=%x:~0,1%&set b=%x:~1,1%&set c=%x:~2,1%&set d=%x:~3,1%
:l
@echo %x%&set k=1&if %a%==0 (if %d% NEQ 0 set/a d=d-1&set k=0) else set/a a=a-1&set k=1
@if %b% NEQ 0 if %k%==1 set/a b=b-1&set k=0
@if %c% NEQ 0 if %k%==0 set/a c=c-1
@if %x% NEQ 0000 set x=%a%%b%%c%%d%&goto l
```

The new solution (fixed according to the underlying comments) is 288 bytes heavy.

Comment: I haven't looked at your answer in great depth, but I am struggling to follow your logic in the first paragraph. Which example specifically are you referring to? And your example of going from `1234` to `0224` is **not** one movement. The idea is that with using only two fingers I can grasp up to three consecutive rings with a single grip.

Comment: I meant, if you can move 3 consecutive rings, it's reasonable to think that you can also move the first and the third one, avoiding the second one. Or should I change my code?

Comment: Your assumption is wrong; you should change your code. Do you see the logic as explained in the above comment?

Comment: Code fixed. I checked with several different types of combinations and it looks to me like it always takes the shorter way.

Comment: This seems to only count downwards, so it takes longer than necessary for combinations with high numbers (e.g. 18 moves for 9999)

Comment: Only count downwards? Not "only" counting. And it is supposed to only change a maximum of 3 digits at a time. It must take 18 moves for 9999.

Comment: @noize what faubiguy means is in combination locks, you can rotate the numbers up or down. Which means for input 9999, should be 2 moves (not 18). 9999 0009 0000. see also example for 9871 in question.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. I'm sorry, I'll fix it now.

Comment: **the space** after `SET/A` & `SET/P` is also unneeded. ex. `set/px=` would work.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell - 310 bytes

```
import Data.Char
import Data.List
r=replicate
h=head
a x=map(:x)[map(`mod`10)$zipWith(+)(h x)((r n 0)++(r(4-j)q)++(r(j-n)0))|j<-[1..3],n<-[0..j],q<-[1,-1]]
x!y=h x==h y
x#[]=(nubBy(!)$x>>=a)#(filter(![(r 4 0)])x)
x#y=unlines.tail.reverse.map(intToDigit<$>)$h y
main=do x<-getLine;putStrLn$[[digitToInt<$>x]]#[]
```

This works by repeatedly building a new list of combinations by applying each possible turn to each combination already reached until one of them is the right combination. Duplicates are removed from the list on each iteration to keep memory usage from growing exponentially.

As a brute force solution, this is very inefficient and can take several minutes to run.

I don't have much experience with Haskell, so some thing could probably be done better.

Comment: Seems like a solid basis for your approach. I've not experience with Haskell, nor (that I know of) any means of compiling/running it. A quick google doesn't give me anywhere I can try it, either. Are you able to give a link which lets me try it? Thanks.

Comment: @Lui It can be compiled with the [Glasgow Haskell Compiler](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/), but apart from downloading and using that I don't know of any way to run it.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E) `--no-lazy`, <s>41</s> <s>39</s> 37 bytes

Lazy evaluation seems to break it, with it enabled, this doesn't terminate.

```
[TS4ã¦ŽΣmbÏD(«N>ãεISšÅ»+}T%¤O1‹i¦J»,q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AU0Asv9vc2FiaWX//1tUUzTDo8Kmxb3Oo21iw49EKMKrTj7Do861SVPFocOFwrsrfVQlwqRPMeKAuWnCpkrCuyxx//85ODcx/y0tbm8tbGF6eQ)

This is really slow, doesn't finish for `1234` and `5555` on TIO.

The general structure of the program is

```
[           infinite loop, N in 0, 1, ...
 ...        generate list of all possible movements
    ...     take all combinations of N+1 movements and convert them to a sequence of positions
       ...  if the current position list ends with 0000, print and terminate
```

In more detail:

```python
TS4ã¦ŽΣmbÏD(«     # generate a list of all possible movements
T                 # push 10
 S                # split into digits ["1", "0"]
  4ã              # take ["1", "0"] to the 4th cartesian power
                  # this generates all 4-digit combinations of 0 and 1
    ¦             # remove the first element ("1111")
     ŽΣm          # push compressed integer 20958
        b         # convert to binary
         Ï        # keep the 4-digit combinations at indices where
                  #   the binary representation of 20958 has a 1
          D       # duplicate the list
           (      # negate each number in the copy
            «     # concatenate both lists
```

[Try `T4ãʒγ€ÙO}¦€SD(«` online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/xOTw4lOTzm1@1LTm8Ez/2kPLgIxgF41Dq///t7QwN/yvq5uXr5uTWFUJAA)

```python
N>ãεISšÅ»+}T%     # try all possible combinations of movements
 N                # push the iteration counter (starts at 0)
  >               # increment the value
   ã              # take the movement list to the N+1 cartesian power
    ε             # map over each list of N+1 moves
     IS           # push the digits of the input
       š          # prepend it to the move list
        Å»+}      # cumulative left-reduce by addition
                  # this generates all positions of the lock
                  # that are a result of the movements in the list
            T%    # modulo 10

¤O1‹i¦J»,q        # verify and print position sequence
¤                 # get the last position
 O                # sum it
  1‹              # is this less than 1? (equal to 0)
    i             # if this is the case:
     ¦            #   remove the first element (initial position)
      J»          #   join each position and positions by newlines
        ,         #   print the result
         q        #   exit
```

Comment: Nice, knew I'd get one-upped by a golf lang eventually

Comment: but the asker is lazy

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 93 bytes

Doesn't even try to be efficient, will run out of memory for 5555 on TIO. :-)

```
(0({s#])((,-)|:#:7 59 217 584),/@((],10|(+{:))"1 2/)^:(]0=1#.s=:(4#0)&e."%.)^:_,:^:2)@(".@,.)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcoxC4MwEAXg3V9xJLS5ozHmUkW9IgiFTp26a4eilC4dHPW/pxnrg8eDj/eJypkZOgEDFjxIau7g@rjfInpcFz0Qos1pEy01VC0ETtOUZIsecbDsNzytQqQYQkGj4OA71m7pBEvt6Tg5dXDJn1ZGCdSjcr11FCnLptf7C3iZCQwH9uYf2qZms3@cyx1UKSb@AA)

- `(".@,.)` convert '0123' into a list like `0 1 2 3`
- `,:^:2` list of list of steps `[[0 1 2 3]]`
- `^:(]0=1#.s=:(4#0)&e."%.)^:_` until the there is a path of moves with `0 0 0 0` in it:
- `((,-)|:#:7 59 217 584)` the possible moves
- `,/@((],10|(+{:))"1 2/)` for each possible move and each path: create a new path with the last move + the possible move, mod 10 appended.
- `0({s#])` filter out the paths that caused the loop to stop, and take the first.